# How to white list firefox extension redirect_uri in google developer console

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-authentication, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am making Firefox extension and implementing google-authentication , problem is that Firefox extension (browser.identity.getRedirectURL()) redirect_uri is not allowed to white list in google developer console, so redirect_uri mismatch error is happening , any guidance in this regard will be appreciate.

First i have implemented google-authentication in chrome extension ,there i have used (chrome.Identity.getAuthToken  && chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo) in chrome but these two function are not avaliable for firefox, for firefox i have created web application project in google developer console , but problem is that redirect_uri mismatching error happening. Google developer project not white listing the url generated by (browser.identity.getRedirectURL())

```
const redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
const clientID = "clientId";
const scopes = ["openid", "email", "profile"];
let authURL = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
```

client_id=${clientID}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(r 
    edirectURL)}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' '))}`;
        return browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
          interactive: true,
          url: authURL
        } , function (done , err) {
            console.log('done' , done);
        });

How to add the extension url in white list, or any other solution to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Firefox 86, you can use a special loopback address as the redirect URI that does not require domain validation with Google. The format of this URI is `http://127.0.0.1/mozoauth2/[subdomain of URL returned by identity.getRedirectURL()]`. Below is an example of how to generate this URI.

```js
const baseRedirectUrl = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
const redirectSubdomain = baseRedirectUrl.slice(0, baseRedirectUrl.indexOf('.')).replace('https://', '');
const redirectUri = 'http://127.0.0.1/mozoauth2/' + redirectSubdomain;
```

Here are some additional details quoted directly from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity#getting_the_redirect_url):

> `identity.getRedirectURL()` returns a URL at a fixed domain name and a
> subdomain derived from the add-on's ID. Some OAuth servers (such as
> Google) only accept domains with a verified ownership as the redirect
> URL. As the dummy domain cannot be controlled by extension developers,
> the default domain cannot always be used.
>
> However, loopback addresses are an accepted alternative that do not
> require domain validation (based on [RFC 8252, section 7.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.3)). Starting
> from Firefox 86, a loopback address with the format
> `http://127.0.0.1/mozoauth2/[subdomain of URL returned by identity.getRedirectURL()]` is permitted as a value for the redirect
> URL.
>
> > Note: Starting with Firefox 75, you must use the redirect URL returned
> > by `identity.getRedirectURL()`. Earlier versions allowed you to supply
> > any redirect URL.
> >
> > Starting with Firefox 86, the special loopback address described above
> > can be used too.